# Why does my HTML5 form not submit the value for my option list with PHP?

Tags: php, html, list, forms, html-select

In my code everything is submitted fine except for the "category" field in the option drop down list. The PHP file that used `$category = $_POST['category'];` can't get the string of text associated with each option value, but assigns the other variables with no problem.

This information from the form is then put into my database, and the user can make a search - all works fine apart from the category field.

```
 <form method="post" action="add_item_action.php">
    <table>
    <tr><td>Item Name:</td> <td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Vendor Name:</td> <td><textarea name="vendor"></textarea></td></tr><tr><td>Item Details:</td> <td><textarea name="description"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item Start Price ($):</td> <td><textarea name="price"></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item </td>
    <tr><td><label>Category:</label></td>
             <td><select id = "category">
           <option value= "1">Select an option</option>
               <option value = "Electronics">Electronics</option>
               <option value = "Cars">Cars</option>
               <option value = "Fashion">Fashion</option>
               <option value = "Pets">Pets</option>
           <option value = "Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>
           <option value = "Books">Books</option>
           <option value = "Sports">Sports</option>
             </select>
            </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Add item">
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 6):

Jquery uses the "ID" or the "class" to identify your elements, however, for a webbrowser to send the form data back to the webserver upon submit, you need the "name" attribute:

```
<select id="category" name="category">
```

Just remember: forms need names!

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate your option text as the option's `value` attribute.  Just omit that bit of markup bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Your select

```
<select id = "category">
```

must have a name to be posted

```
<select id = "category" name="category">
```

user input values withou a name will not be posted.

All your other have one :) why not your category ..?

Answer (score 0):

add `name` attribute here

```
<select id = "category" name="category">
```

and access in `add_item_action.php` like this

```
$_POST['category']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your select box you have just given

```
<select id = "category">
```

give it as

```
<select id = "category" name="category">
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `name=category`

```
<select id = "category" name="category">
    <option value= "1">Select an option</option>
    <option value = "Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value = "Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value = "Fashion">Fashion</option>
    <option value = "Pets">Pets</option>
    <option value = "Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>
    <option value = "Books">Books</option>
    <option value = "Sports">Sports</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate your option text as the option's `value` attribute.  Just omit that bit of markup bloat.